# jQuery slideDown with easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

How can use the slideDown() function with easing?

Maybe extend it somehow?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.slideDown = function(speed, easing, callback) {
  return ...
};
```

So i can use it slide this

```
$('.class').slideDown('400','easeInQuad');
```

or this

```
$('.class').slideDown('400','easeInQuad',function(){
   //callback
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at this page, which contains many easing functions: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Using that plugin you can do things like:

```
$(element).slideUp({
    duration: 1000, 
    easing: method, 
    complete: callback});
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the animate method with jQueryUI and the [easing effects](http://ralphwhitbeck.com/demos/jqueryui/effects/easing/) like this:

```
$(".demo").animate({height: "hide"}, 1500, "easeInQuad", function(){});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - no need for another plugin.  Thanks.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Easing In and Out:

```
            $("#SignIn").click(function () {

                $(".divSlideTop").slideDown({
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: "easeInQuad"
                });
            });

            $("#close").click(function () {

                $(".divSlideTop").slideUp({
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: "easeOutQuad"
                });
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.class').slideDown(400,'easeInQuad');
```

Quotes not need for numeric.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at my pen [Demo](http://codepen.io/Shaz3e/full/grBLv) you simple to use `$(element).slideUp({duration:1000});`